# Intersection problems with ray-sphere intersection

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection, raytracing

I'm writing a simple ray tracer and to keep it simple for now I've decided to just have spheres in my scene. I am at a stage now where I merely want to confirm that my rays are intersecting a sphere in the scene properly, nothing else. I've created a Ray and Sphere class and then a function in my main file which goes through each pixel to see if there's an intersection (relevant code will be posted below). The problem is that the whole intersection with the sphere is acting rather strangely. If I create a sphere with center (0, 0, -20) and a radius of 1 then I get only one intersection which is always at the very first pixel of what would be my image (upper-left corner). Once I reach a radius of 15 I suddenly get three intersections in the upper-left region. A radius of 18 gives me six intersections and once I reach a radius of 20+ I suddenly get an intersection for EACH pixel so something is acting as it's not supposed to do.

I was suspicious that my ray-sphere intersection code might be at fault here but having looked through it and looked through the net for more information most solutions describe the very same approach I use so I assume it shouldn't(!) be at fault here. So...I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong, it could be my intersection code or it could be something else causing the problems. I just can't seem to find it. Could it be that I am thinking wrong when giving values for the sphere and rays? Below is relevant code

**Sphere class:**

```
Sphere::Sphere(glm::vec3 center, float radius) 
: m_center(center), m_radius(radius), m_radiusSquared(radius*radius)
{
}

//Sphere-ray intersection. Equation: (P-C)^2 - R^2 = 0, P = o+t*d
//(P-C)^2 - R^2 => (o+t*d-C)^2-R^2 => o^2+(td)^2+C^2+2td(o-C)-2oC-R^2
//=> at^2+bt+c, a = d*d, b = 2d(o-C), c = (o-C)^2-R^2
//o = ray origin, d = ray direction, C = sphere center, R = sphere radius
bool Sphere::intersection(Ray& ray) const
{
    //Squared distance between ray origin and sphere center
    float squaredDist = glm::dot(ray.origin()-m_center, ray.origin()-m_center);

    //If the distance is less than the squared radius of the sphere...
    if(squaredDist <= m_radiusSquared)
    {
        //Point is in sphere, consider as no intersection existing
        //std::cout << "Point inside sphere..." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //Will hold solution to quadratic equation
    float t0, t1;

    //Calculating the coefficients of the quadratic equation
    float a = glm::dot(ray.direction(),ray.direction()); // a = d*d
    float b = 2.0f*glm::dot(ray.direction(),ray.origin()-m_center); // b = 2d(o-C)
    float c = glm::dot(ray.origin()-m_center, ray.origin()-m_center) - m_radiusSquared; // c = (o-C)^2-R^2

    //Calculate discriminant
    float disc = (b*b)-(4.0f*a*c);

    if(disc < 0) //If discriminant is negative no intersection happens
    {
        //std::cout << "No intersection with sphere..." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else //If discriminant is positive one or two intersections (two solutions) exists
    {
        float sqrt_disc = glm::sqrt(disc);
        t0 = (-b - sqrt_disc) / (2.0f * a);
        t1 = (-b + sqrt_disc) / (2.0f * a);
    }

    //If the second intersection has a negative value then the intersections
    //happen behind the ray origin which is not considered. Otherwise t0 is
    //the intersection to be considered
    if(t1<0)
    {
        //std::cout << "No intersection with sphere..." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << "Intersection with sphere..." << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Program:**

```
#include "Sphere.h"
#include "Ray.h"

void renderScene(const Sphere& s);

const int imageWidth = 400;
const int imageHeight = 400;

int main()
{
    //Create sphere with center in (0, 0, -20) and with radius 10
    Sphere testSphere(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f), 10.0f);

    renderScene(testSphere);

    return 0;
}

//Shoots rays through each pixel and check if there's an intersection with
//a given sphere. If an intersection exists then the counter is increased.
void renderScene(const Sphere& s)
{
    //Ray r(origin, direction)
    Ray r(glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f));

    //Will hold the total amount of intersections
    int counter = 0;

    //Loops through each pixel...
    for(int y=0; y<imageHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<imageWidth; x++)
        {
            //Change ray direction for each pixel being processed
            r.setDirection(glm::vec3(((x-imageWidth/2)/(float)imageWidth), ((imageHeight/2-y)/(float)imageHeight), -1.0f));

            //If current ray intersects sphere...
            if(s.intersection(r))
            {
                //Increase counter
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution (`t1`) to the quadratic equation is wrong in the case `disc > 0`, where you need something like:

```
float sqrt_disc = glm::sqrt(disc);
t0 = (-b - sqrt_disc) / (2 * a);
t1 = (-b + sqrt_disc) / (2 * a);
```

I think it's best to write out the equation in this form rather than turning the division by 2 into a multiplication by 0.5, because the more the code resembles the mathematics, the easier it is to check.

A few other minor comments:

1. It seemed confusing to re-use the name `disc` for `sqrt(disc)`, so I used a new variable name above.
2. You don't need to test for `t0 > t1`, since you know that both `a` and `sqrt_disc` are positive, and so `t1` is always greater than `t0`.
3. If the ray origin is inside the sphere, it's possible for `t0` to be negative and `t1` to be positive. You don't seem to handle this case.
4. You don't need a special case for `disc == 0`, as the general case computes the same values as the special case. (And the fewer special cases you have, the easier it is to check your code.)

Comment: I've updated my code above according to some of the things you said. I used a new variable name for better clarity and also removed the case where disc == 0, which after all is not necessary as you said. I also fixed the error of the second solution where I missed a - sign as pointed out. You are right about the third case, I assume the easiest way of checking this is to simply see if the distance between the ray origin and the sphere center is less than tha radius and if it is then no intersection (of my interest) occurs.

Comment: I agree with writing out the code as close to the formulas as possible but when looking through the net the reason I went with my current approach is because it was recommended to avoid problems with calculations in floating-point format. So I'm slightly unsure if I should change that part or not. Either way, the update is above but the same problem remains unfortunately

Comment: Your computation of `t0` and `t1` is still wrong! Try the code I gave in my answer instead.

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the late reply. I went with the code you provided. I also added the third case that you mentioned. Thanks for the suggestions, very helpful things that I should have thought of! Just want to mention though that it didn't change the underlying problem I had which was solved by Benny Smith's answer. Once I had it working with your (and Benny Smith's) code I also tried the code I had before this current update and it did give the same working result, so except the miss of a minus sign you pointed out I'm not entirely sure if that part of my code was actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you might want to try:

```
r.setDirection(glm::vec3(((x-imageWidth/2)/(float)imageWidth),
                         ((imageHeight/2-y)/(float)imageHeight),
                         -1.0f));
```

Right now, you've positioned the camera one unit away from the screen, but the rays can shoot as much as 400 units to the right and down.  This is a very broad field of view.  Also, your rays are only sweeping one octent of space.  This is why you only get a handful of pixels in the upper-left corner of the screen.  The code I wrote above should rectify that.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I do have to admit though that I am confused on what's going on. It's been a while but first I was wondering how you determined the distance between the camera and my projection/image plane. You said it is one unit away and the only way I could draw that conclusion is that my camera ("start" pos. of ray) is at the origin and my direction vector happen to be pointing at an XY-plane where z = -1.0. Not sure if this is the right way to think of it

Comment: But if it is one unit away you are right that it would have a broad field of view (which is not good). Wouldn't this be solved though by moving the start position of my ray further back? Anyway to the more important part, the code you provided solved the problem but I don't have a good idea of what exactly is happening. If you do not mind, could you elaborate on what you mean with my rays only sweeping one octent of space and of course why(!) they are doing so, and then how they relate to only getting pixels in the upper-left corner? Finally how does the code you gave me solve it?

Comment: I've been looking at it but I just can't wrap my head around what's happening. I'm sorry for the many questions but at the moment, while I'm having a working solution, I don't really know what my code is exactly doing. So a more detailed explanation would be highly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply.  The vector you are providing above is a ray that travels through space (hence "ray tracing").  In your original code, the values for x and y would range from 0 to 400, while z remains a constant at -1.  Therefore, they would only travel in the portion of space where x and y are positive (the first octent) and in the extreme case, the ray is stepping 400 units to the right for every one unit it moves forward.  In the code I wrote, x and y range from -0.5 to 0.5, while z remains constant at 1 - this gives you a 45 degree field of view.

Comment: I found this website with some useful information on field-of-view in ray tracing:
http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/graphics/rt_eyerays.html